# compiling materializeCSS framework for new color variable gives error

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors

I am trying to add a new color palette to MaterializeCSS framework.

I downloaded the source and installed `Sass` on my machine.

Here are the steps I followed to try to achieve my goal.

1. I have added a custom file `_customblue.scss` to `materialize-src\sass\components` The code can be seen in the bottom of this post.
2. I included it in the `materialize.scss` file like so `@import "components/customblue";`. And I imported it before any of the variable files were imported.
3. I then edited `_variables` to my liking. I will also add this codeblock in the botom of this post.

Once I compile this with `sass materialize.scss materialize.css` I get the following output:

```
WARNING: Unknown `customblue` - `base` in $colors.
    components\_color-variables.scss 368:3  color()
    components\_variables.scss 37:17        @import
    materialize.scss 9:9                    root stylesheet

Error: $color: null is not a color.
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  components\_variables.scss 38:23  @import
  materialize.scss 9:9              root stylesheet
```

`_customblue.scss`:

```
$customblue: (
  "base":       #002B48,
  "lighten-5":  #f2faff,
  "lighten-4":  #9dd7ff,
  "lighten-3":  #48b5ff,
  "lighten-2":  #0090f2,
  "lighten-1":  #005e9d,
  "darken-1":   #002137,
  "darken-2":   #001726,
  "darken-3":   #000d15,
  "darken-4":   #000204
);
```

`_variables.scss`:

```
$primary-color: color("customblue", "base") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;

$secondary-color: color("customblue", "lighten-2") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;
$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what I did wrong!

I removed the imported file I made earlier, instead I now put these colors in `_color-variables.scss` and then in the bottom of this file there's an array where you have to add your color.

```
$colors: (
  "materialize-red": $materialize-red,
  "customblue": $customblue,
  .....
) !default;
```

I hope this is useful for someone in the future.